# Mail Validator, invalid address if separated by commas

Tags: regex, email, kettle, email-validation

In my transformation application, i have a simple mail validator.
I am taking the address from a big database, and sometimes the `email_to` column contains more than one comma separated address.

From the documentation of the mail step:

> Destination address 
>   The destination for the email. This can be a single address, a comma-separated list of addresses (use a space, not a comma), or an email alias for a distribution list

[mail step documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Mail+(step))

I think that the mail validator is able to know if the string contains more than one address.
But it doesn't work. If I send a comma separated address, it becomes "invalid".

How to validate this kind of string?
Is there a way to modify the regular expression to validate the address?

The documentation does not cover comma separated email adresses.
[Mail Validator](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Mail+Validator)

I have tried to combine all emails, with no success.
[image: Some try...]

Comment: Read the QUESTION!
the validator doesn't not validate the "space separated" mail address. Look at the row 5 of the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue...

[image: the workaround]

I make another validator, with a simple js, that check each mail address.

```
var mailString = EMAIL_TO.toString();
var elements = mailString.split(", ")  //The separator for the mail sender
var email_to_result=true;

for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
       if(!isMailValid( elements[i] )){
        email_to_result = false;
        email_to_errors = "Mail not valid"; //i've added all the wrong mail
    }
}
```

So, if i've multiple mail, it pass the validation. But if only one of this mail, is not valid, all the mail is not valid.